# how can i find the minutes difference in this timeformat?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, date, datetime-format

```
05-Dec-19 08.30.00.000000000
05-Dec-19 08.31.00.000000000
```

i want do find the minutes difference between these two time formats in mysql(phpmyadmin 5.7.x)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You appear to be storing datetimes as strings. So you would first need to convert these strings to dates (for this, you can use [`STR_TO_DATE()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date)); then you can use [`timestampdiff()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampdiff) to compute the difference in minutes:

```
timestampdiff(
    minute,
    str_to_date(mycol1, '%d-%b-%y %H.%i.%s.%f'),
    str_to_date(mycol2, '%d-%b-%y %H.%i.%s.%f')
)
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=defcc50114dc4d3b7b44c34ce1fb8d6c)**:

```
select 
    str_to_date('05-Dec-19 08.30.00.000000000', '%d-%b-%y %H.%i.%s.%f') date1,
    str_to_date('05-Dec-19 08.31.00.000000000', '%d-%b-%y %H.%i.%s.%f') date2,
    timestampdiff(
        minute,
        str_to_date('05-Dec-19 08.30.00.000000000', '%d-%b-%y %H.%i.%s.%f'),
        str_to_date('05-Dec-19 08.31.00.000000000', '%d-%b-%y %H.%i.%s.%f')
    )minutes_diff
```

```
date1                      | date2                      | minutes_diff
:------------------------- | :------------------------- | -----------:
2019-12-05 08:30:00.000000 | 2019-12-05 08:31:00.000000 |            1
```